# MongoDB select an object and Sort by a distinct field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a table something link this:

```
_id    title    provider_id    product_id     price
 1       a           20             1          50
 2       b           21             1          30
 3       c           23             1          60
 4       d           20             2          50
 5       e           21             2          20
 6       f           20             3          80
 7       g           21             3          60
 8       h           23             3          50
```

what I'm trying to get is, select rows with highest **prices** and with distinct **product_id**, So I can define the product and know which **provider**.
I know that mongodb `distinct` doesn't support `sort`, so I've tried this:

```
db.getCollection('product_details').aggregate([
      {$match: {_id: {$ne: null}}},
      {$group: {_id: {_id:"$product_id"}}},
      {$sort: {price: 1}},
      {$limit:20},
      {$skip:0}
])
```

but mongodb gives only the product_id as _id, that its reasonable why but its useless.
Is there a way to get all the object (or row) by distinct product_id and sort them at the same time?

ps: as `{$match: {_id: {$ne: null}}}` I mean some simple condition.

tnx

Comment: use $max on price in conjunction with $group.  Then you can remove $sort.

Comment: also, I don't think _id can be null, so the first $match is not used.

Comment: Sort is not the problem, as I said the problem is that product_id returns as _id and the real _id is missing

Comment: understood.  The $group is an aggregation function.  If it groups by this field, then it needs to understand what to do with the other fields since they are not participating in the grouping.  By using the $max in conjunction with $group you have instructed the database engine on how to include the price data.  You still have not identified what to do with the provider_id, however.  Having said this, if done properly ($max with $group) you do not need the $sort.  Since you have not provided the $max on price, price will not be included in the pipeline and $sort does nothing.

Comment: can u send me an example of how to write it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need entire object, Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$match: {_id: {$ne: null}}}, 
{ $sort: { price: -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$product_id', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $project: { _id: 0, data: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data", 0] } } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }])
```

Here `{$match: {_id: {$ne: null}}}` doesn't really help you, as `_id` ideally won't be null unless you insert it, that too as it's unique it might exist for only one document.

Comment: Interesting approach - sort by price descending first, push all the data in sorted order into "data" property, then take only the first element in each grouping.

Comment: thank you, about `_id: {$ne: null}` , I said its just to show that I want to add some conditions.

Comment: sorry but it seems that sort doesnt work, should I call it $data.price or something like this?

Comment: @Godfather  : what is issue ? Can you give us sample docs, as sort is first stage then if it’s in an object it has to be called as objectname.price, I can suggest looking at sample docs but from the table above query should work as expected..I’ve tested it using sample data at my end..

Comment: `db.getCollection('product_details').aggregate([
 {"$match":{price:{$ne:null}}},
 {"$sort":{"data.price":1}},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$product_id","data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$project":{"_id":{price:"$data.price"},"data":{"$arrayElemAt":["$data",0]}}},
 {"$limit":32},
 {"$skip":0},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])` , the result is completely regardless to $sort

Comment: @Godfather : In the sort we no need to use ‘data.price’ if price is a top level field in the document. Also data is a field being created in ‘$group’ stage which will not be available for prior stage ‘$sort’

Comment: @Godfather : From your query `skip` can be removed, also why is `limit` on distinct data, Is that really needed ?

Comment: @srinivas yes the sort is needed and the problem was I needed to use sort at end of the query, when I put it there, it worked properly